# playin sound inside CountdownTimer doesnt stop

Tags: java, android

i have this code for downtime counter :

```
CountDownTimer CountdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         txttime.setText( millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         play_sound();
     }

     public void onFinish(){
         timeout_stage(); //call an activity
     }
  }.start();
```

my problem is that when i call `CountdownTimer.cancel();` this two lines should stop:

```
txttime.setText( millisUntilFinished / 1000);
play_sound();
```

but now, setting text to txttime stops but playing sound not!  why?

this is my play_sound();

```
    public void play_sound(){
    MediaPlayer mp;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.success);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `mp.start()` starts its own thread, that will run on background even if you cancel the `countDownTimer`.

Try cancelling or stopping `mp`.